# How to create a query that show the result into column and not in rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to get a Query to select some row from a table but I want to show the results not on rows but on column.

So for example:

```
SELECT V.IDPARAMETER AS ID, V.VALUE AS VALUE
FROM AA_V_RESULTS V
WHERE V.ID = ?
```

The result of this query is

```
ID  VALUE
150 177
151 IN THE NORM
152  OK
```

Now I want that the result is this:

```
if(id = 150)
   name of column is 'PARAMETER1'
else if(id = 151)
   name of column is 'PARAMETER2'
else if(id = 152)
   name of column is 'PARAMETER3'
```

So the result of the query is

```
PARAMETER1 PARAMETER2 PARAMETER3
177        IN THE NORM OK
```

It is possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select 
  max(case [ID] when 150 then [VALUE] end) as [Parameter1],
  max(case [ID] when 151 then [VALUE] end) as [Parameter2],
  max(case [ID] when 152 then [VALUE] end) as [Parameter3]
from [your_table_name];
```